# Why a browser only supports GET and POST HTTP methods?

Tags: http, browser

I read the following text from [Apress Apache Tomcat 7](http://www.apress.com/9781430237235)

> The HttpServlet.service() method implementation is a convenient way to
>   control access to your servlets in the code. For example, servlets
>   that delete data from the database should always be accessed using the
>   DELETE method, **but because browsers only support GET and POST
>   operations, the POST method should be used instead.**

It seems most browsers only supports 2 HTTP methods, `GET` and `POST`.

If so, why?

Comment: Can you give an example of some other method you think they should support and what that support might look like?

Comment: I haven't seen a single browser only supporting `GET` and `POST`. How did you come to this conclusion? `PATCH` is unusual still though.

Comment: @Hampus I added the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are modern browsers which allow GET, POST, PUT and DELETE using the XMLHttpRequest. You can go through this [bug 10671](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=10671)

> Executing PUT and DELETE to modify resources on the origin server is
>   straight-forward for modern Web browsers using the XmlHttpRequest
>   object. For unscripted browser interactions this not so simple.
>   Typically, devs and frameworks end up creating work-arounds that mimic
>   the HTTP PUT/DELETE + Etag interaction using a "POST FORM" coupled
>   with specialized server-side code to sort out the special case and act
>   as if the proper HTTP Method was used in the request
>
> Other considerations:
>
> - Using POST as a tunnel instead of using PUT/DELETE can lead to
>     caching mis-matches (e.g. POST responses are cachable5, PUT responses
>     are not[6], DELETE responses are not[7])
> - Using a non-idempotent method (POST) to perform an idempotent
>     operation (PUT/DELETE) complicates recovery due to network failures
>     (e.g. "Is is safe to repeat this action?").

You can also refer this thread: [Are the PUT, DELETE, HEAD, etc methods available in most web browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers)

Comment: I mark this answer because the link is very useful. Guffa's answer is concise and I prefer this one.

Answer (score 3):

In a form the only possible methods are GET and POST. When you make an AJAX call, other methods are supported.

[`<form>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3):

> **method = get|post** [CI]
>       This attribute specifies which HTTP method will be used to submit the form data set. Possible (case-insensitive) values are "get" (the
>   default) and "post".

[`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest):

> **method**
>       The HTTP method to use, such as "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", etc. Ignored for non-HTTP(S) URLs.

Comment: Voted for being concise. Thanks.